# How to format request in HTTP.jl to include cert file

Tags: http, julia

I would like to know how to include a cert file when sending requests in [HTTP.jl](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/stable/public_interface/#Requests-1).

In Python, using `Requests` it would look like this,

```
   requests.get(url, params=payload, verify=cert_file)
```

The documentation mentions SSL certs, but is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It really is poorly documented, and in similar cases I've had to look at the source code to 
MbedTLS (within the site https://tls.mbed.org/), which is what the package HTTP.jl calls for certificates.

MbedTLS in turn looks for the systems's installed certificates, so if you install the certificate for your user, HTTP.jl should use it for https. I realize this may not help your specific need, which may require something like this (untested):

```
using HTTP, MbedTLS

conf = MbedTLS.SSLConfig(cert_file, key_file)
resp = HTTP.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", sslconfig=conf)

println(resp)
```

itself.

If you have to go back to the MbedTLS source as I did, I suggest you look at the example at https://github.com/JuliaLang/MbedTLS.jl and the source at 
https://github.com/JuliaLang/MbedTLS.jl/blob/master/src/MbedTLS.jl, 
especially the function SSLConfig(cert_file, key_file) on line 103.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bill–I'll definitely check those things out. And yeah, I hate to cast judgement on a young project, but the documentation is really poor. It feels like a bait and switch from the (perhaps overly ambitious) promise of a language for those "who want it all".

Comment: Python's Requests package library did not even exist when Python was at its 1.3 stage, where Julia is now. The libraries can be expected to improve.

Comment: I added an improved example in my answer above.